# In Java how does one turn a String into a char or a char into a String?

Tags: java, string, char

Is there a way to turn a `char` into a `String` or a `String` with one letter into a `char` (like how you can turn an `int` into a `double` and a `double` into an `int`)? (please link to the relevant documentation if you can).

How do I go about finding something like this that I'm only vaguely aware of in the documentation?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

```
char firstLetter = someString.charAt(0);
String oneLetter = String.valueOf(someChar);
```

You find the documentation by identifying the classes likely to be involved. Here, candidates are `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.Character`.

You should start by familiarizing yourself with:

- Primitive wrappers in `java.lang`
- Java Collection framework in `java.util`

It also helps to get introduced to the API more slowly through tutorials.

- [Manipulating characters in a String](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html)

Comment: see the relevant javadoc for documentation

Answer (score 17):

`String.valueOf('X')` will create you a String `"X"`

`"X".charAt(0)` will give you the character `'X'`

Answer (score 13):

As no one has mentioned, another way to create a String out of a single char:

```
String s = Character.toString('X');
```

> Returns a String object representing the specified char. The result is
>   a string of length 1 consisting solely of the specified char.

Answer (score 3):

```
String someString = "" + c;
char c = someString.charAt(0);
```

Comment: The `"" + 'c'` uses autoboxing and is not recommended, because it first does `"" + Character.toString('c')` and then `"" + "c"` and then `"c"`. It does the extra `"" + "c"` operation, which can slow down the program if used too often.

Answer (score 1):

```
String g = "line";
//string to char
char c = g.charAt(0);
char[] c_arr = g.toCharArray();
//char to string
char[] charArray = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String str = String.valueOf(charArray);
//(or iterate the charArray and append each character to str -> str+=charArray[i])
```

//or String s= new String(chararray);

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: @Radiodef - They added in `toCharArray()` which was exactly what I was looking for. No other answer that existed at the time mentioned it.

Answer (score -1):

In order to convert string to char

```
 String str = "abcd";
char arr [] = new char[len]; // len is the length of the array
arr = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: You're needlessly allocating a char array of length 'len' just to be overwritten in the next line

Answer (score -2):

I like to do something like this:

```
String oneLetter = "" + someChar;
```

Comment: I strongly dislike it, because it doesn't convey the intent. You don't want to do any addition or concatenation, so `+` is not the right thing to use here.