# Whitespaces in java

Tags: java, whitespace

What are kinds of whitespaces in Java?
I need to check in my code if the text contains any whitespaces.

My code is:

```
if (text.contains(" ") || text.contains("\t") || text.contains("\r") 
       || text.contains("\n"))   
{  
   //code goes here
}
```

I already know about `\n` ,`\t` ,`\r` and `space`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731055/whitespace-matching-regex-java

Comment: I had to change one line of code to `if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)) || Character.isSpaceChar(text.charAt(i))) {` to get the results I wanted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
boolean containsWhitespace = false;
for (int i = 0; i < text.length() && !containsWhitespace; i++) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(text.charAt(i)) {
        containsWhitespace = true;
    }
}
return containsWhitespace;
```

or, using Guava,

```
boolean containsWhitespace = CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.matchesAnyOf(text);
```

Comment: or put that in a method to return the boolean and avoid the awkward `break` and "accumulator" variable.

Comment: Would there be any reason here to use [Character#isWhitespace(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) instead of the suggested [Character#isWhitespace(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char))?

Comment: @MartinAndersson (2 years late) the [Character#isWhitespace(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) version accepts a [codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) which you would get using [Character#codePointAt(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#codePointAt(char[],%20int)). The codepoint could span multiple chars in the string. For example the documentation mentions that is detects LINE_SEPARATOR and PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR '\u2007', '\u202F' which are more than 8 bits wide

Comment: The `!containsWhiteSpace` test should come first, not last, and in any case the variable is redundant, as the `true` case can be replaced by `return true` and the fall-through case by `return false`.

Comment: Or you can leave the loop with break; after containsWhitespace was set to true. This would lead to a simpler condition in the for loop.

Answer (score 23):

For a non-regular expression approach, you can check [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) for each character.

```
boolean containsWhitespace(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

> Which are the white spaces in Java?

The documentation specifies what Java considers to be whitespace:

> `public static boolean isWhitespace(char ch)`
>
> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java. A character is a Java whitespace character if and only if it satisfies one of the following criteria:
>
> - It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or    PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space
>     ('\u00A0',    '\u2007', '\u202F').
> - It is `'\u0009'`, HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
> - It is `'\u000A'`, LINE FEED.
> - It is `'\u000B'`, VERTICAL TABULATION.
> - It is `'\u000C'`, FORM FEED.
> - It is `'\u000D'`, CARRIAGE RETURN.
> - It is `'\u001C'`, FILE SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001D'`, GROUP SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001E'`, RECORD SEPARATOR.
> - It is `'\u001F'`, UNIT SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to consider a regular expression based way of doing it

```
if(text.split("\\s").length > 1){
    //text contains whitespace
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29) rather than creating your own.

[In Java how does one turn a String into a char or a char into a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429228/in-java-how-does-one-turn-a-string-into-a-char-or-a-char-into-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use apache.commons.lang in your project, the easiest way would be just to use the method provided there:

```
public static boolean containsWhitespace(CharSequence seq)
```

Check whether the given CharSequence contains any whitespace characters.

> Parameters:
>
> ```
> seq - the CharSequence to check (may be null)
> ```
>
> Returns:
>
> ```
> true if the CharSequence is not empty and contains at least 1 whitespace character
> ```

It handles empty and null parameters and provides the functionality at a central place.

Answer (score 0):

From sun [docs](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/):

> \s    A whitespace character: [ \t\n\x0B\f\r]

The simplest way is to use it with regex.

Comment: The *only* way to use `\s` is with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean whitespaceSearchRegExp(String input) {

    return java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher(input).find();

}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please check the guideline to give a good answer. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if text.trim() has a different length? :

```
if(text.length() == text.trim().length() || otherConditions){
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Because it creates another `String`, for a start.