# Does Java regard a 'normal' space as whitespace for the purposes of Character.isWhitespace?

Tags: java, whitespace, spaces

This might seem to be a no-brainer at first glance. It probably is, but a few things have me feeling I might be missing something.  First [the Java documentation for Character.isWhitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace-char-) seems to exclude it.  The definition for what is and what is not allowed as whitespace seems very definitive ('if and only if') and the first line says *not* a non-breaking space.

I have always regarded an ordinary 'space' - that thing you get when you press a spacebar - as a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

So where does it fit in the list? The list is regarded as definitive in the highest rated answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863503/whitespaces-in-java) - am I simply reading it wrong?
Also, the first commenter to the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936374/is-there-an-invisible-character-that-is-not-regarded-as-whitespace) seems to have his doubts (in a different context).  Yet when I construct a simple bit of code to test, it indicates that a normal space is an instance of whitespace, as one would expect.

```
import static java.lang.Character.isWhitespace;

public class WhitespaceCheck {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        Character test = ' ';

        if (Character.isWhitespace(test)) {
            System.out.println("Is whitespace!" );                        
        } else {
            System.out.println("Is not whitespace!" );
        }
    }
}
```

So, am I reading the first item on the list wrongly, is it somewhere else on the list, or is the list itself simply wrong?

Comment: I think the documentation _does_ state that it is included, because `SPACE_SEPARATOR` is `U+0020` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I have used non-breaking spaces in Microsoft Word to prevent a line break from occurring between words that I really wanted to be kept together. They were entered using Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar. They should not be confused with the character that is usually produced by pressing the spacebar alone.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nearly there! As the other answer says, `U+0020` is included in the category of Unicode covered by SPACE_SEPARATOR.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are mistaken; a non-breaking space prevents a line break. It's a special type of space and not a "normal" one which does allow a line break. If a "normal" space was a non-breaking space then lines would never wrap when you reached the edge of the screen unless you pressed return manually each time.

The very first line says:

> It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ('\u00A0', '\u2007', '\u202F')

A list of unicode whitespace covered by SPACE_SEPARATOR can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

The documentation for [SPACE_SEPARATOR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#SPACE_SEPARATOR) says that it is referring to a category of Unicode characters, not a specific character.  The 'normal' space of the title (which is what is usually produced by the spacebar) is included in this category.