# How to assign a single char to a TextView

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to assign a single char to a TextView in Android Java.
Using a string works:

```
textView.setText("X");
```

But using a char aborts at runtime:

```
textView.setText('X');
```

and:

```
char Key5 = 'X';  
textView.setText(Key5);
```

Using a Character also aborts at runtime:

```
Character Key5 = 'X';  
textView.setText(Key5);
```

Typecasting the Character to a string does work:

```
Character Key5 = 'X';  
textView.setText(Key5.toString());
```

How do I assign a plain char variable to a TextView?

Comment: duplicate off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429228/in-java-how-does-one-turn-a-string-into-a-char-or-a-char-into-a-string

Comment: textView.setText(String.valueOf(Key5));

Answer (score 9):

You can "convert" a character into a String with the method String.valueOf(char):

```
char key = 'X';
textView.setText(String.valueOf(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

You can't, you must use a CharSequence. (Thanks [Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267661/sam))

Long answer:

The problem is that [TextView.setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) is not overloaded to take a character as the only parameter. It can only take a CharSequence.

From the [CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html) documentation

> This interface represents an ordered set of characters and defines the methods to probe them.

String works because it implements the CharSequence inteface. It doesn't make sense to have a CharSequence that only holds one character

Comment: I think this is the better answer to the question: "How do I assign a plain char variable to a TextView?" (i.e. You can't, you must use a CharSequence.)